# iframe returns homepage instead of external file

Tags: html, iframe, joomla, adobe-edge

I'm trying to embed a html5 banner created in Adobe Edge, the simplest way I could think of was dumping all the code edge spits out onto the ftp and then using an iframe to point at the html file. If I do this locally on my machine it works fine, if I try it on our live site the top left corner of the website is what appears in the iframe instead of the banner. It's a Joomla 1.5 site I have no idea what would cause this as I've not used iframes before. I've edited the code so it no longer has spaces.

Here is my website: [www.webchild.com.au](http://www.webchild.com.au)

and here is the iframe code:

```
<iframe src="/stdAds/html5/bilby-test/bilby_theatrical_banner.html" width="300" height="250" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>
```

The code inside the html file is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge"/>
<title>Bilby Theatrical Productions Banner</title>
<!--Adobe Edge Runtime-->
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="bilby_theatrical_banner_edgePreload.js"></script>
<style>
.edgeLoad-EDGE-380725615 { visibility:hidden; }
</style>
<!--Adobe Edge Runtime End-->

</head>
<body style="margin:0;padding:0;">
<div id="Stage" class="EDGE-380725615">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please provide a link to your website, along with the code you're using for the iFrame.

Comment: <iframe src="/stdAds/html5/bilby-test/Bilby%20Theatrical%20Banner.html" width="300" height="250" frameborder="0" scrolling="no"></iframe>

Comment: 404 for the link. That file doesn't exist, which is why you get the home page (404 forwards to index)

Comment: The file is definitely there, it's weird because I placed a helloworld.html file next to it to check that it would work and it opened correctly but the file I want just wont open.

Comment: Hold up, I've moved it up one file, removing the bibly-test and it no longer 404s, will check iframe again now this may have fixed it though I don't understand why.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the spaces out of your link. It may well be the `%20`'s replicating the spacebar are screwing up the link. Else have you checked the html file your including is definately in the correct location on your FTP. If you just try going straight to the link ( http://www.webchild.com.au/stdAds/html5/bilby-test/Bilby%20Theatrical%20Banner.html ) you can see there is a 404 error which is probably why the top of your site is appearing - the 404 error page rather than the page

Comment: I removed the spaces and that hasn't fixed it, the file is definitely at that file path. File permissions for it are correct to, I can only think maybe our SEF404 plugin is causing the issue?

Comment: It's possible. It should be straight forward to check that though. turn off SEF urls and disable the SEF404 plugins (as a temporary measure) and see what happens. Try referencing something else in the same folder as well.